# NSTableColumn in NSOutlineView: how to size columns to fit on expand/collapse?

Tags: xcode4.2, osx-snow-leopard, appkit

[Using Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard.  OSX, not iOS]

In IB, I created an outline view, and set up a view controller to be it's data source.  When I expand/collapse a row, the 1st column resizes for indentation.  When I double-click the column header resizers, the columns resize to fit their current contents.

How can I invoke *that* size-to-fit behavior on expand/collapse?  I can use the `outlineViewItemDidExpand:` and `outlineViewItemDidCollapse:` to call a resizing method, but I can't find what method *does* the default size-to-fit.  I'd rather not reimplement it if it's something Apple makes available.

Comment: After using `instrumentObjcMessageSends();`, it appears that the double-click cause `_sizeToFitWidthOfColumn:` to be invoked on the `NSOutlineView`, which passes it off to `NSTableView`.  Shortly thereafter, `_delegate_sizeToFitWidthOfColumn:` is invoked on `NSOutlineView`, and `setWidth:` on `NSTableColumn`.  Unfortunately, both of those size-to-fit methods are private.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any way to invoke it, but it's probably just as well.  While experimenting, I saw the fact that for larger tables (over 100), the default behavior doesn't always find the largest.  I guess I'll just have to code up a *real* size-to-fit. :(